# grep word after matching + tab

Tags: linux, bash

I am really new to coding/linux
I am trying to find a line contain `XX Number      1.2.3.4` or `XX Number      1.2.-.-`

Initially I am only hard coding by doing

```
grep "XX Number" filename | cut -c 15-
```

but then I realize there are some files that have word "XX Number" in their line which will screw up.

Here is an example (note that the multiple spaces are a literal tab):

```
XX Number       1.2.3.4
XX Number       1.2.-.-
Another line with XX Number that shouldn't match
```

Here's what I currently get:

```
$ grep "XX Number" filename | cut -c 15-
1.2.3.4
1.2.-.-
ith XX Number that shouldn't match
```

Here's what I want:

```
1.2.3.4
1.2.-.-
```

How do I grep the for XX Number + tab then only show the 1.2.3.4 or 1.2.-.-?

Thanks

Comment: Please post some sample inputs and expected outputs for same.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I added some examples based on your description so that people can easily see what data you work on, what you get and what you wanted. Please look over it and edit as appropriate!

Comment: thank you for help me organize this. I edit the output I had and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/XX Number\t1\.2\.(3\.4|-\.-)/' file

XX Number       1.2.3.4
XX Number       1.2.-.-
```

to get the part of the last field

```
$ awk '/XX Number\t1\.2\.(3\.4|-\.-)/{sub("1.2.","",$NF); print $NF}' file

3.4
-.-
```

Comment: this is another nice method. Regular expression is just very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` with tab included:

```
grep $'XX Number\t' filename | cut -c15-
```

Output:

```
3.4
-.-
```

Or, if you want the whole field:

```
grep $'XX Number\t' filename | cut -f2
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.4
1.2.-.-
```

Tab is the default delimiter for `cut`.

Comment: thanks, this is what I am looking for where to include tab after the word.

Comment: However, is this count as hard code? is there anyway to grab whatever word/number after match without setting the range?

Comment: Yes, you could use `cut -f2-` to grab everything from field 2 onwards.

Comment: I don't really understand filed 2 onward. but I tried and it did not work with     -f2-

Comment: Just like how `cut -c15-` outputs all characters from 15th position onwards, `cut -f2-` would output all fields starting with the second one.  Your sample file has only two fields separated by a tab and hence `-f2-` isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to print lines where a substitution succeeds, so don't print by default (`-n`) and print after substitution (`.../p`).

```
sed -n 's/^XX Number\t....//p' filename
```

or when you do nut want to remove 4 chars after the TAB:

```
sed -n 's/^XX Number\t//p' filename
```